# Microsoft SQL Server CE Check if table exists

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to check if a table exists in Microsoft SQL Server, but somehow the function I use always returns that it doesn't exist, and the output doesn't specify that an exception was thrown.

This occurs both before I created the table (which is expected), as well as after I created the table (which is not expected).

This is the function I am using:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks  if a certain Sql Server Table exists
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_databasename">The name of the database</param>
/// <param name="_password">The password of the database</param>
/// <param name="_tablename">The name of the table to check</param>
/// <returns>
///     'true' if table exists
///     'false' if table not exists or if an exception was thrown
/// </returns>
public Boolean TableExists(String _databasename, String _password, String _tablename)
{
    if (!_databasename.Contains(".sdf")) { _databasename = _databasename + ".sdf"; }
    try
    {
        String connectionString = "DataSource=" + _databasename + "; Password=" + _password;
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

        if (conn.State==ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }

        using (SqlCeCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Information_Schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + _tablename + "'";
            Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Table " + _tablename + " does not exist.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Table " + _tablename + " exists.");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception _ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to determine if table " + _tablename + " exists: " + _ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

There clearly is something I am missing here, but I just can't seem to find out what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executescalar%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) returns the first column of the first row retrieved by the query.
Supposing that your table really exist, the database name is correct and in the expected location, then the first column of the row returned is from TABLE_CATALOG, a nvarchar column.

Pheraphs you could try to change your query to:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Information_Schema.Tables " + 
                      "WHERE TABLE_NAME = .......";
```

Said that, I still can't explain why you don't get an exception when you try to convert to an int the return value of ExecuteScalar.....

Comment: this still doesn't work for me. it keeps returning the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Then you should check the database name. Are you working with Visual Studio and have the Copy Always set to true for the sdf file?

Comment: I am working with SharpDevelop, and using private databases for my project. as for Copy Always; i didn't set it to true, but i dont know if it is set to true by default.

Comment: I have no knowledge of SharpDevelop. I don't even know if Copy Always exist there. In VS if this property is true, then every time you compile the project the file is copied to the working debug directory. Of course this new copy destroys any change made to the working copy. Have you checked if the path passed in is correct?

Comment: if you mean wether the database file exists in my debug folder, yes it does. but it does not copy there every time i run the application. it checks if the database file is there, and if it is, it does nothing.

Comment: i just got my code to work using your example. somehow the bug originated in a completely different part of my code, which i thought was unrelated to the subject.

thanks for your help.